# "101: Product not exists." (Magento API) product.update

Tags: php, excel, soap, magento-1.9

I saw the [documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.update.html) but I still not finding the error on my code.

I am trying to **add a product from excel** file to Magento System, and then **update it on each Store View** (multi language shop).

For that, I've done the following PHP script. On this code, I'm reading only one Excel row (just to show you how it works) and then i am adding it to Magento (actually that's **working**) and then I am trying to Update stuff (gives the **error**). Be aware that $col[9] is the var that saves the SKU.

**Note:** I am using SOAP, but not V2.

```
$rowdata=$sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row.':'.$maxcol . $row, NULL, TRUE, FALSE);
$col=$rowdata[0];
//$soap is the client. $session_id is the logged in SOAP session.
$attributeSets = $soap->call($session_id, 'product_attribute_set.list');
$attributeSet = current($attributeSets);
$result = $soap->call($session_id, 'catalog_product.create', array('simple',     $attributeSet['set_id'], $col[9], array(
    'categories' => array(2),
    'websites' => array(1),
    'name' => $col[1],
    'description' => $col[10],
    'short_description' => $col[13],
    'weight' => '10',
    'status' => '1',
    'url_key' => 'product-url-key',
    'url_path' => 'product-url-path',
    'visibility' => '4',
    'price' => $col[20],
    'tax_class_id' => 1,
    'meta_title' => 'Product meta title',
    'meta_keyword' => 'Product meta keyword',
    'meta_description' => 'Product meta description'
)));
var_dump ($result);
$updatearray=  array(
    'name' => $col[2],
    'description' => $col[11],
    'short_description' => $col[14]
);
$update = $soap->call($session_id, 'catalog_product.update',    array($col[9], $updatearray, 'fr'));
var_dump ($update);
```

I would appreciate any help you guys can give!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the **fix** for this problem but it really makes no sense.

So, when we are sending the SKU by call, we need to send with an extra space. It means the $update needs to be like this:

```
 $soap->call($session_id, 'catalog_product.update',    array($col[9].' ', $updatearray, 'fr'));
```